# How do I isolate the win32_* member type from get-ciminstance win32_groupuser | select partcomponent

Tags: powershell

My goal is to get the group members from a windows server, using powershell; determine if they are AD domain users or groups, and if a group, drill down into the AD group to get the userids and full names.

So far, I've tried get-ciminstance win32_groupuser, then feed that to Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association win32_groupuser, but it's excruciatingly slow. I've tried net localgroup, and split the result into variables, and feed them to get-aduser and get-adgroupmember. That works, but it's a text based kludge, relying on an outside utility. I haven't been able to figure out how to get the member type from the partcomponent output.

```
$localgroup = Get-ciminstance -class win32_groupuser | where { (($_.groupcomponent).name -eq "Administrators") -and (($_.groupcomponent).domain -eq "$env:computername")} | select partcomponent
    foreach ($groupmember in $localgroup)
        {   
            <#$domain = $groupmember.partcomponent.domain
            $username = $groupmember.partcomponent.name#>
            $account_type = ($groupmember -split " |=|""")[1]
            $account_type = $account_type.trim()
            $member_name = ($groupmember -split " |=|""")[6]    
            $member_name = $member_name.trim()
            $domain = ($groupmember -split " |=|""")[12]
            $domain = $domain.trim()    
            write-host "Domain: $domain Group Member: $member_name Account Type: $account_type"
            pause
            if ($domain -match "domain_1")
                {
                    if ($account_type -match "group")
                        {
                            $userid = Get-ADGroupMember -server domain_1.com -identity "$member_name" | select samaccountname
                            $username = Get-ADGroupMember -server domain_1.com -identity "$member_name" | select fullname
                        }
                    elseif ($account_type -match "user")
                        {
                            $userid = Get-ADuser -server domain_1.com -identity "$member_name"| select samaccountname
                            $username = Get-ADuser -server domain_1.com -identity "$member_name" | select fullname
                        }
                }       
        }       

PartComponent
-------------
Win32_UserAccount (Name = "Administrator", Domain = "server1")
Win32_Group (Name = "Domain Admins", Domain = "domain_1")
Win32_UserAccount (Name = "_SVC_account", Domain = "domain_1")
Win32_Group (Name = "domain_group1", Domain = "domain_1")
Win32_Group (Name = "SEC_server1_LocalAdmins", Domain = "domain_1")
Win32_Group (Name = "SrvAdmins", Domain = "domain_1")
Win32_UserAccount (Name = "Admin-userid1", Domain = "domain_2")
Win32_Group (Name = "ServerAdmins", Domain = "domain_2")
```

Comment: [1] if you have ps5.1 you can use the `Get-Local*` cmdlets provided by the `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` module that comes with ps5.1 by default. [2] you can also use the ADSI stuff to search both local groups and reach out to ActiveDirectory servers.

Comment: I’m aware of the 5.1 cmdlets, but I’m a contractor, working in a large corporate AD migration, gathering information from potentially hundreds of servers, across the world. The OS versions vary from 2003-2016, and their powershell versions aren’t all 5.1. I have to run this script on a jump server, which also doesn’t have 5.1 installed, because I can’t log on to my workstation with admin credentials, and powershell script execution is blocked on my workstation. My options are somewhat limited. I see that partcomponent is a noteproperty, and appears to be perhaps a hashtable of hashtables?

Comment: ah! so you can't use anything that won't work on psv2. that makes sense. [*grin*] ///// however, the answer by postanote shows how to use ADSI to get that info in a MUCH cleaner fashion. the CIM/WMI stuff is ... obtuse ... at best.

Answer (score 0):

There are several modules that cover local machine / user management on the Microsoft PowerShellGallery.com

```
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/LocalMachine/1.3

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/localaccount/1.6

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/LocalUserManagement/3.0
```

You can then use those results to use the ADCmdlets…

```
Get-ADGroup
Get-ADGroupMember
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

… using that username or group discovered to get the information you are after.

Now, as noted, you can just use ADSI directly.
Walk though example relative to each data point you are after.

As for ...

> My goal is to get the group members from a windows server

```
# get host groups and group membership
$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME # get-content computers.txt

$computers | 
foreach {
    $computername = $_

    [ADSI]$S = "WinNT://$computername"
    $S.children.where({$_.class -eq 'group'}) |
    Select @{Name="Computername";Expression={$_.Parent.split("/")[-1] }},
    @{Name = "Name";Expression = {$_.name.value}},
    @{Name = "Members";Expression = {
            [ADSI]$group = "$($_.Parent)/$($_.Name),group"
            $members = $Group.psbase.Invoke("Members")
            ($members | ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ";"
        }
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize



# Results

    Computername Name                                Members                                     
------------ ----                                -------                                     
LabSvr01     Access Control Assistance Operators                                             
LabSvr01     Administrators                      Administrator;Domain Admins;...         
LabSvr01     Backup Operators                                                                
...                                                          
LabSvr01     Event Log Readers                                                               
LabSvr01     Guests                              Guest  
...
```

As for ...

> determine if found users are AD domain members

```
$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME # get-content computers.txt

$HostGroupData = $computers | 
foreach {
    $computername = $_

    [ADSI]$S = "WinNT://$computername"
    $S.children.where({$_.class -eq 'group'}) |
    Select @{Name="Computername";Expression={$_.Parent.split("/")[-1] }},
    @{Name = "Name";Expression = {$_.name.value}},
    @{Name = "Members";Expression = {
            [ADSI]$group = "$($_.Parent)/$($_.Name),group"
            $members = $Group.psbase.Invoke("Members")
            ($members | ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ";"
        }
    }
}

# Validate local or domain membership
($HostGroupData.Members -split ';').Trim() | 
? {$_.Length -gt 0} | 
Get-ADUser  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select Name,UserPrincipalName,SID | 
Format-Table -AutoSize


Name                           UserPrincipalName           SID                                           
----                           -----------------           ---                                           
Administrator                  Administrator@contoso.com S-1-5-21-...
...
Guest                                                      S-1-5-21-3...
...
```

As for ...

> determine if found groups are AD domain groups

```
# Validate if the discoverd group is a domain group
($HostGroupData.Name -split ';').Trim() | 
? {$_.Length -gt 0} | 
Get-ADGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select Name,GroupCategory,GroupScope ,DistinguishedName,SID | 
Format-Table -AutoSize


Name                                GroupCategory  GroupScope DistinguishedName        SID                            
----                                -------------  ---------- -----------------        ---                            
Access Control Assistance Operators      Security DomainLocal CN=Access ...            S-1-5...                  
Administrators                           Security DomainLocal CN=Administrators...     S-1-5...                   
Backup Operators                         Security DomainLocal CN=Backup Operators...   S-1-5...
...
```